# Wave soldering with screws/spacers

Tags: pcb, soldering, heatsink

I wonder if it's possible to use certain screws/spacers in a wave soldering machine, so that it will be possible to screw a screw to the spacer attached to the PCB afterwards?

My intial thought is that maybe a titanium screw/spacer might work due to poor [Solder-ability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solderability) but I have no clue if that works.

To understand the problem; I've a heatsink that has to be screwed to the PCB before soldering the TO-220 packages to the PCB. The reason to this is to minimize stress on the legs due to the stiff fitting till the heatsink (only available solution for my application). So I would like to find a solution where it's not necessary to hand solder this specific part, which is the case right now.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

That kind of thing is usually handled by a peelable solder mask applied before the board goes through the machine.

[image]

Comment: If not my question was misunderstood. The answear is that a solder mask can be applied on a spacer that is mounted on the PCB which will be in the wave solder?

I'm going to use a spacers that looks like this: [link](http://i00.i.aliimg.com/img/pb/281/530/376/376530281_256.jpg)

Comment: Yes @AntonIngemarson, The mask is applied as a preparation step to places you do not want soldered and removed after soldering and cleaning. It can be to holes you want left open, as in the image, or on top of screws or other parts that would be damaged by the heat.

Comment: Though I am a little confused why you would want the spacer pre-mounted on the underside of the board.

Comment: Perhaps you need to add a mechanical drawing / sketch to the question to clarify.

Comment: The reason is that I want to make sure that no mechanical stress is applied after soldering, because the heatsink for this application has to be solid tightened to the case on both the upper side and lower side to make sure it survive extreme acceleration that the device will be exposed to during it's life cycle.

Comment: There is a limit to how far things can protrude under the board though. Show us a drawing.

Comment: YOu may need to insert a temporary screw for the wave process than replace with the stand off after.

Comment: And BTW: Solid coupling to the case is not generally the best approach for protection against High-Gs.

Comment: @AntonIngemarson Generally it's not the best idea to get "random brass spacer" and put it through any soldering process if you want to rely on it. There are actual components that can be soldered onto a board in both wave and reflow systems that allow screws to be connected, designed for the purpose, allowing you to use well tested solder openings and profiles in the board design. An example of what I have recently reflowed onto a PCB in large quantities: http://katalog.we-online.com/en/em/WP-SMBU_THROUGH-HOLE?sid=a9d2ec293f

Comment: Thank you all the answers!

However I do wonder; What are the other ways to protect against High-Gs?

Comment: @AntonIngemarson, think of your motor car. If you were solidly attached to the front bumper, and it hit a wall... even at only 5-10km an hour... YOU would ALSO be hitting a wall at 5-10km an hour and suddenly stop with 100s of Gs.. You would have significant injuries. Instead cars have a buffer and a crumple zone so you, the cargo, stop MUCH slower than the front bumper. It is better if your circuit boards are securely but less firmly attached to the case via plastic or even rubber fastenings, capable of withstanding the sheer forces, so the board has a longer time to stop.